# PHP & Ajax: manage list update

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a chat service based on polling:
every 20 seconds a script is run on server (by every client) to retrieve new user in chat-room.
I want to optimize this.
I want to download data only for new users that just entered the chat, I don't want to re-download old data about old users.
I could solve by sending in the request the userid of people I already have, check if there are new users and apped their data to the list on client; I think this is better than before... but ... is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  There is a better way.  Use web sockets to distribute changes to clients in real time:

http://socketo.me/

On the client side, https://www.websocket.org/

Comment: I have an Apache server on a shared host, can I use web-sockets?? Can I use web-sockets with only PHP knowledge?

Comment: I read the documentation and it seems terrific stuff! However it requires some study by me but I have no time (at the moment, but it will be the newt thing I'll learn). Is there an alternative, better way?

Comment: @Ferex You're either long polling or short polling.  Long polling, you keep the connection open and you only transmit data when you need to. Short polling, you're sending periodic requests, like you're doing now.  If you want to use long polling, you need to learn about it (web sockets).  If you just want to reduce the amount of information you send, you could record the login time of users, and only send them information about users that have left or joined since they joined, or since they last received an update.

Comment: At the moment I have javascript which makes Ajax requests every 15 seconds. To avoid sending my list in the request and check the differences in the db I could send the request, and in the PHP script I can compare my time-activity (which is a column for every user) with other users time-activity. If my time-activity is higher than other user's I don't do nothing, else I download stuff (for newer users). Of course in this case I must update my time activity. Is it right??